# BigQuery synchronous query is not returning any results

Tags: google-bigquery

According to the BigQuery documentation listed at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#asynchronous-queries:

There are two types of querying via the BigQuery API. Synchronous and Asynchronous. Async works perfectly for me using the sample code provided, however synchronous does not.

The sample code I am referring to is shown if you click on the link above. What I noticed is that it does not actually wait until the results are available. If I insert a `time.sleep(15)` before the `while True`, my results return as expected. If not, then the it returns an empty result set.

The official documentation example uses the query:

```
    """SELECT word, word_count
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
    WHERE corpus = @corpus
    AND word_count >= @min_word_count
    ORDER BY word_count DESC;
    """
```

This query returns very quickly, however my query takes several seconds to return a result.

My question is, why does the documentation state that the `run_sync_query` command waits until the query completes, if the results are not actually accessible and no results are returned?

I cannot provide the query I used because it is a private data source. To produce, you just need a query that takes several seconds to run.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the [request/call is timing out](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#timeoutMs), not the query itself. The default time is 10s. Try setting `timeout_ms` in your code:

[image]

For example (I'm going to assume you are using Python):

```
..[auth/client setup stuff]..

query = client.run_sync_query('<your_query>')
query.timeout_ms = 60000 #set the request timeout
query.use_legacy_sql = False
query.use_query_cache = True
query.run()

..[do something with the results]..
```

Comment: Thanks, I didnt realize that this method had a timeout setting. Seems best to always use the other method.