# BigQuery Timeout Errors in R Loop Using bigrquery

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I am running a query in a loop for each store in a dataframe.  Typically there are 70 or so stores so the loop repeats that many times for each complete loop.

Maybe 75% of the time this loop works all the way through with no errors.

About 25% of the time I get the following error during any one of the loop iterations:

Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached

Then I have to figure out which iteration bombed, and repeat the loop excluding iterations that completed successfully.

I can't find anything on the web to help me understand what is causing this seemingly random error.  Perhaps it is a BQ technical issue?  There does not seem to be any relation to the size of the result set it crashes on.

Here is the part of my code that does the loop...again it works all the way through most of the time.  The cartesian product across IDs is intentional, as I want every combination of each Test ID with all possible Control IDs within store.

```
sql<-"SELECT pstore as store, max(pretrips) as pretrips FROM analytics.campaign_ids 
  group by 1 order by 1"

store_maxtrips<-query_exec(sql,project=project, max_pages = 1)
store_maxtrips

for (i in 1:length(store_maxtrips$store)) {

  #pull back all ids shopping in same primary store as each test ID with their pre metrics  
  sql<-paste("SELECT a.pstore as pstore, a.id as test_id, 
  b.id as ctl_id,
    (abs(a.zpbsales-b.zpbsales)*",wt_pb_sales,")+(abs(a.zcatsales-b.zcatsales)*",wt_cat_sales,")+
  (abs(a.zsales-b.zsales)*",wt_retail_sales,")+(abs(a.ztrips-b.ztrips)*",wt_retail_trips,") as zscore
  FROM analytics.campaign_ids a inner join analytics.pre_zscores b
  on a.pstore=b.pstore
  where a.id<>b.id and a.pstore=",store_maxtrips$store[i]," order by a.pstore, a.id, zscore")

  print(paste("processing store",store_maxtrips$store[i]))

  query_exec(sql,project=project,destination_table = "analytics.campaign_matches",
         write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND", max_pages = 1)
  }
```

Comment: how long do these queries typically take to execute in the Web UI?

Comment: They are pretty fast, ranging between 6 and 20 seconds each. I'd say the average is about 12 seconds.

Comment: You are most likely hitting the default 10s timeout - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41494059/bigquery-synchronous-query-is-not-returning-any-results/41495950#41495950

Comment: I know some queries take longer than 10 seconds and no error is reported.  But in any case I'd like to try increasing the default and see if that resolves it.

I am using the bigrquery package in R to run the loop but I can't find anywhere to change the timeout setting.  Do you know of any way I can set the timeout setting for a BigQuery session in R?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see anything in the R codebase to let you set it like you can in Java/Python. Although, I'm not really that familiar with R. I know someone who is an expert. I'll get him to have a look at this question.  https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=timeout

Comment: Thank you Graham!  I have to think there is a way to do this.  Maybe we can get the author of the bigrquery package to add it.  It's such a pain having to restart all the time.

Comment: I really don't think it is a timeout issue.  I have queries that run in BQ from R in the same connection for a few minutes at a time without issues.  It seems it is only when I run them in a loop (and the max they run is maybe 20 seconds) is when I get the error.  If we find a way to increase the default timeout setting I am all for trying it, but I'm skeptical that it will fix this issue.

Comment: Hi Mark, good name. Graham directed me to the question. I guess that its because bigrquery is using the same HTTP handler that is getting conflicts when run in a loop.  It doesn't fix the issue (you may want to raise an issue on https://github.com/rstats-db/bigrquery/issues ) but you could put the query_exec in a try() statement, and retry if the output is of class "try-error" e.g. response <- try(query_exec(....etc...); if(inherits(response, "try-error")) {---retry---}

Comment: Thank you MarkeD for your suggestion.  I will give it a shot.  If I can at least trap the error with this and have it automatically restart, that would solve my issue of having to manually intervene each time.  I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

It turns out I was using query_exec, but I should have been using insert_query_job since I do not want to retrieve any results.  The errors were all happening in the course of R trying to retrieve results from BigQuery which I didn't want anyhow.

By using insert_query_job + wait_for(job) in my loop instead of the query_exec command, it eliminated all issues with the loop finishing.

I did also need to add a try() function to help circumvent some rare errors that still popped up with this approach.  Thanks to MarkeD for this tip.  So my final solution looked like this:

try(job<-insert_query_job(sql,project=project,destination_table = "analytics.campaign_matches",
             write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"))
  wait_for(job)

Thanks to everyone who commented and helped me research the issue.